# Can I determine which Amazon customer/account is looking after a particular AWS-hosted site?

Tags: amazon-aws

Given just the domain name and the knowledge that a public website with that address is hosted on AWS (by means of the IP address etc.), is there anyway of finding out any information about who is responsible for administering that site,  i.e. whose AWS account it is?

Comment: Is this about a [website under your control](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)? If not, then this would considered off-topic here. You could of course look for WHOIS information for the domain, or contact information in the site, but Amazon isn't going to relay that information due to their privacy policy.

Comment: It's supposed to be under our control but currently isn't due an issue with a partner going out of business. But yeah I suspected Amazon wouldn't give out that info, just wondering.

Answer (score 1):

Due to privacy reasons Amazon will not under any circumstances give out customer information like that even if you can demonstrate that the site is under your control. You could attempt to contact Amazon and ask them to forward an email from you to the account holder requesting that he make contact with you but i sincerely doubt that they will do that.